# How can I find the Cartesian Product of a list of vectors?

Tags: python, list, iterator, permutation

I'm having an issue I can't wrap my head around at the moment. Basically, I have data formatted in a way like this:

- there is a Vector with a certain number of elements (say, three, so let's use `(1, 2, 3)` as an example. In this example, the dimension would be 3.
- this vector is repeated in a list for `n` number of times

So I have in this example `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]` if `n = 2`. What I now want is a new list of vectors, where each element inside a Vector in the list is combined with every other element in the others. In this example, my expected output would be:

`[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]`

Now, for a small list like this, this could be done using simple loops, but my question is: **How can I write a function that would give me all such combinations for Input Vectors of `x` dimension and `y` number of such Vectors in the list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to need `itertools.product`:

```
a = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3)]

list(product(*a))
#[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Your approach won't return the expected output; it won't return `(3,3)`, for example, because despite the OP's terms, he's not looking for permutations.

Comment: @zipa how can I improve the title to make the question more clear?

Comment: @aliasguru Name for this kind of operation is [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)